# How to get all different records in two different spark rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Very very new to spark and RDD's so I hope I explain what I'm after well enough for someone to understand and help :)

I have two very large sets of data, lets say 3 million rows with 50 columns which is stored in hadoop hdfs.
What I would like to do is read both of these into RDD's so that it uses the parallelism & I would like to return a 3rd RDD that contains all records (from either RDD) that do not match.

Below hopefully helps show what I'm looking to do...
Just trying to find all different records in the fastest most efficient way...

Data is not necessarily in the same order - row 1 of rdd1 may be row 4 of rdd2.

many thanks in advance!!

[image: Example of datasets & desired result]

So... This seems to be doing what I want it to, but it seems far to easy to be correct...

```
%spark

import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

//create the tab1 rdd.
val rdd1 = sqlContext.sql("select * FROM table1").withColumn("source",lit("tab1"))

//create the tab2 rdd.
val rdd2 = sqlContext.sql("select * FROM table2").withColumn("source",lit("tab2"))

//create the rdd of all misaligned records between table1 and the table2.
val rdd3 = rdd1.except(rdd2).unionAll(rdd2.except(rdd1))

//rdd3.printSchema()    
//val rdd3 = rdd1.except(rdd2)

//drop the temporary table that was used to create a hive compatible table from the last run.
sqlContext.dropTempTable("table3")

//register the new temporary table.
rdd3.toDF().registerTempTable("table3")

//drop the old compare table.
sqlContext.sql("drop table if exists data_base.compare_table")

//create the new version of the s_asset compare table.
sqlContext.sql("create table data_base.compare_table as select * from table3")
```

This is the final bit of code i've ended up on so far which seems to be doing the job - not sure on performance on the full dataset, will keep my fingers crossed...

many thanks to all that took the time to help this poor pleb out :)

p.s. if anyone has a solution with a little more performance I'd love to hear it!
or if you can see some issue with this that may mean it will return the wrong results.

Comment: rdd.fullOuterJoin can be used.

Comment: is there anything special to get it all distributed over all nodes?

Comment: not very large imho

Comment: `fullOuterJoin` wont work you might need `df1.leftOuter.df2 union df2.leftOuter.df1` with  conditions

Comment: haha
@ thebluephantom - it is actually a lot larger than that, just didnt have the actual figures off the top of my head :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Load your both Dataframes as `df1`,`df2`
2. Add a `source` column with default value as `rdd1` and `rdd2` respectively
3. Union `df1` and `df2`
4. Group by `"rowid", "name", "status", "lastupdated"` and collect its sources as set
5. Filter all rows which has single source

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object OuterJoin {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess

    import spark.implicits._

    val cols = Array("rowid", "name", "status", "lastupdated")

    val df1 = List(
      ("1-za23f0", "product1", "active", "30-12-2019"),
      ("1-za23f1", "product2", "inactive", "31-12-2019"),
      ("1-za23f2", "product3", "inactive", "01-01-2020"),
      ("1-za23f3", "product4", "inactive", "02-01-2020"),
      ("1-za23f4", "product5", "inactive", "03-01-2020"))
      .toDF(cols:_ *)
      .withColumn("source",lit("rdd1"))

    val df2 = List(
      ("1-za23f0", "product1", "active", "30-12-2019"),
      ("1-za23f1", "product2", "active", "31-12-2019"),
      ("1-za23f2", "product3", "active", "01-01-2020"),
      ("1-za23f3", "product1", "inactive", "02-01-2020"),
      ("1-za23f4", "product5", "inactive", "03-01-2020"))
      .toDF(cols:_ *)
        .withColumn("source",lit("rdd2"))

    df1.union(df2)
      .groupBy(cols.map(col):_ *)
      .agg(collect_set("source").as("sources"))
      .filter(size(col("sources")) === 1)
      .withColumn("from_rdd", explode(col("sources") ))
      .drop("sources")
      .show()
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @QuickSilver

I think I'm getting close, however I get an error with the union

<console>:310: error: value union is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
           df1.union(df2)

assuming this is possibly because we are currently stuck with some old versions and unable to upgrade at the moment.

If I change it to unionAll

I get an output of:
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
main: (args: Array[String])Unit

Not sure if this makes a difference, but i am using the spark interpreter in zeppelin.

Comment: Nope :(

sc.version - res7: String = 1.6.3
util.Properties.versionString - res8: String = version 2.10.5

Comment: You should be able to union RDDs and group by them on custom key only the code will get bit lengthy @torz

Comment: That is what I was looking to do originally but got lost trying to do it, let me see if i can find what i had started a week or two ago when i had a quick look...

Comment: I've just added to my original question to show what seems to be working, the first few results i've looked at so far have been all good. But seems far to easy to be correct? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

you can rather read the data into dataframes and not into Rdds  and then use union and group by to achieve the result

Comment: I was thinking of this originally but thought i read somewhere that it doesn't distribute over all nodes properly...
If it does, then that is great, much more comfortable using pandas df's

Comment: it does , behind the hood it creates RDD only and when we create a Dataframe it automatically palatalizes on the default nodes/configuration

Answer (score 0):

Both can be joined with "full_outer", and then filter applied, where field value compared in both:

```
val filterCondition = cols
  .map(c => (col(s"l.$c") =!= col(s"r.$c") || col(s"l.$c").isNull || col(s"r.$c").isNull))
  .reduce((acc, c) => acc || c)

df1.alias("l")
  .join(df2.alias("r"), $"l.rowid" === $"r.rowid", "full_outer")
  .where(filterCondition)
```

Output:

```
+--------+--------+--------+-----------+------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+------+
|rowid   |name    |status  |lastupdated|source|rowid   |name    |status  |lastupdated|source|
+--------+--------+--------+-----------+------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+------+
|1-za23f1|product2|inactive|31-12-2019 |rdd1  |1-za23f1|product2|active  |31-12-2019 |rdd2  |
|1-za23f2|product3|inactive|01-01-2020 |rdd1  |1-za23f2|product3|active  |01-01-2020 |rdd2  |
|1-za23f3|product4|inactive|02-01-2020 |rdd1  |1-za23f3|product1|inactive|02-01-2020 |rdd2  |
+--------+--------+--------+-----------+------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+------+
```